# Webrtc: how to broadcast one student to all participants

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a WebRTC system that has one teacher, 10 or more students. The architecture is every student only connects to teacher.

The students are not interconnected since the network bandwidth is not as good as teacher, if too much connection may cause congestion.

But I now have a requirement that one student may need to broadcast to all students as well as the teacher(eg. the student is answing a question)

At this time I don't want this student to connect to all other students, for the reason I mentioned above.

Is it possible use teacher as a proxy since the all the students have connected to teacher? I googled one possible method to route the teacher's speaker(the student's voice can be heared) to teacher's microphone, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reponse will be different depending of your project , for a commercial use I think you would need a server implementation to correctly route your media where you want independantly of any of the client.

However, for a project where you must only connect in P2P, you idea of "proxy" could work, you could do something like following. All your student are connected to the teacher sending and receiving a media, while the teacher is connected to all of them, add a new media to the peer at start in recv only for the student and send only for the teacher, using the [Transceivers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getTransceivers) API the teacher could controls wich media to send or note, and forward it to the student.

A second solution could be to mix the audio and send resulting stream in place of the teacher stream , [this webrtc demo could help you](https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiStreamsMixer), i don't know  much about browser compatibility and delays that could occurs.